# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module with dynamic import of Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, suneditor

I followed the doc of SunEditor, it's like:

```
import React from 'react';
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import 'suneditor/dist/css/suneditor.min.css'; // Import Sun Editor's CSS File

const SunEditor = dynamic(() => import("suneditor-react"), {
  ssr: false,
});

const MyComponent = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p> My Other Contents </p>
      <SunEditor />
    </div>
  );
};
export default MyComponent;
```

It works well, but when I add `setOptions` into `SunEditor`:

```
import { buttonList } from "suneditor-react";
...
 <SunEditor
   setOptions={{buttonList:buttonList.complex}}
/>
```

I got this error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Am I missing something, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the same reason you have to dynamically import `SunEditor`, you also have to dynamically import `buttonList`.

One approach is to create a custom component where you add all the suneditor code.

```js
import React from 'react';
import SunEditor, { buttonList } from 'suneditor-react';

const CustomSunEditor = () => {
    return <SunEditor setOptions={{ buttonList: buttonList.complex }} />;
};

export default CustomSunEditor;
```

Then, dynamically import that component with `next/dynamic` where needed.

```js
const CustomSunEditor = dynamic(() => import('../components/CustomSunEditor'), {
    ssr: false,
});

const MyComponent = props => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p> My Other Contents </p>
            <CustomSunEditor />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: i can't think out this way, thanks so much!!!