# SunEditor plugins are not working in nextJs

Tags: next.js, suneditor

I am getting errors while using plugins for suneditor-react. I have imported suneditor like this:

```
import "suneditor/dist/css/suneditor.min.css"; // Import Sun Editor's CSS File
//
const SunEditor = dynamic(() => import("suneditor-react"), {
  ssr: false,
});
//
const plugins = dynamic(() => import("suneditor/src/plugins"), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

I am using sundEditor like this:
Editor is working fine but not the plugins.

```
const getSunEditorInstance = (sunEditor) => {
    editor.current = sunEditor;
  };
      <SunEditor
          getSunEditorInstance={getSunEditorInstance}
          lang="en"
          placeholder="Please type here..."
          autoFocus={true}
          setOptions={{
            height: "80vh",
            code: "en",
            buttonList: [
              ["undo", "redo"],
              [
                "bold",
                "italic",
                "underline",
                "strike",
                "subscript",
                "superscript",
                "fontColor",
                "hiliteColor",
                "align",
                "outdent",
                "indent",
                "list",
                "removeFormat",
              ],
              ["image", "table"],
              ["showBlocks", "codeView"],
            ],
            plugins: plugins
          }}
          setDefaultStyle="font-family: cursive; font-size:16px;"
          disable={loading}
          onChange={handleChange}
          handleImageUploadBefore={handleImageUploadBefore}
          onImageUpload={handleImageUpload}
          setContents={content}
          setAllPlugins={true}
        />
```

Error:
When I click on any plugin like the image upload option:
[see error screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47zex.png)

Comment: Rather than dynamically importing `suneditor-react`, you could use `next/dynamic` on the component where it's used. See [SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module with dynamic import of Nextjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71477581/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-with-dynamic-import-of).

Answer (score 0):

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const SunEditor = dynamic(() => import('suneditor-react'), {
  ssr: false
});
import 'suneditor/dist/css/suneditor.min.css'; // Import Sun Editor's CSS File

const Editor = ({placeholder, value, onChange}) => {
  return (
    
      <SunEditor
        lang="en"
        height={"150px"}
        placeholder={'Type here....'}
        setOptions={{
          resizingBar: false,
          buttonList: [
            [
              'formatBlock',
              'bold',
              'underline',
              'italic',
              'strike',
              'blockquote',
              'showBlocks',
              'fontColor',
              'hiliteColor',
              'align',
              'list',
              'table',
              'link',
              'image',
              'video',
              'removeFormat'
            ]
          ]
        }}
        defaultValue={value}
        onChange={(val) => onChange(val)}
      />
  );
};

export default Editor;
```

Answer (score 0):

use something like it:

```
import React from 'react';
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import 'suneditor/dist/css/suneditor.min.css'; // Import Sun Editor's CSS File

const SunEditor = dynamic(() => import("suneditor-react"), {
  ssr: false,
});

const MyComponent = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p> My Other Contents </p>
      <SunEditor />
    </div>
  );
};
export default MyComponent;
```